# Summing up the values in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 25 slots and each slot fills up with the click of the corresponding button. I'm having an issue summing up the values of the array. I have tried

```
for(var k = 0; k < price.length; k++)
{
    totalPrice += price[k] << 0;
}
```

But this just seems to append the price onto the end of the previous output instead of adding together.

My current code is this:

```
$("#sumArray").click(function()
{       
    a++;
    price[0] = 8.45 * a;
    alert(price[0]);
    for(var k = 0; k < price.length; k++)
    {
        totalPrice += price[k] << 0;
    }
    alert(totalPrice);
    for(var i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        $("#priceHere"+i+"").append("<b>"+totalPrice+"</b>");
    }
    //$.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu1");
});
```

All the other array indexes get filled in other click functions.

EDIT: Removed all code not related to question for ability to read easier.
the price array indexes can change depending on how many times a certain button is clicked.

Comment: I assume your referring to the text array and commented out totalPrice variable?

Comment: You might consider converting those text values to something which can be numerically added? otherwise you'll only get concatenation.

Comment: @QuinnRoundy the text array isn't my issue atm. It's the price array

Comment: Make a jsfiddle, and specify assumptions and requirements at one place (such as you are doing for mobile, and array values change) not here and there in comments

Comment: @cswl Yeah, that's just there temporarily. I'm gonna make it cleaner later on

Comment: Ah, okay.. :) But please edit your question with all the details. Its hard to follow for anyone except @SebastianNette   :/  Though the info was 
**But this just seems to append the price onto the end of the previous output.**

Comment: All code not relating to the question has been removed for easier reading

Comment: @John What exactly is not supposed to append? Is the previous sum not supposed to append to the new sum or is the html output not supposed to append to the previous html output? Either way, you could try one of the solutions from my answer. If both don't solve your issue then it would be helpful if you could provide a fiddle or snippet.

Answer (score 2):

For modern browsesrs (IE 9+ and anything else)

```
total = price.reduce(function (prev,curr) {
   return prev + curr;
}, 0);
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: I should note that I am doing this for a mobile app, so browser compatibility isn't a thing I need to worry about

Comment: Perfect.  `.reduce()` is made exactly for things like summing an array.

Answer (score 1):

Add this before your calculation:

```
totalPrice = 0;
```

If you don't reset the value it just keeps adding to the previous output.

Since the question keeps being edited:

```
$("#priceHere"+i+"").append("<b>"+totalPrice+"</b>");
```

Does, what it says. It appends the total price to the element.
If you want to overwrite the value completely, you could do:

```
$("#priceHere"+i+"").html("<b>"+totalPrice+"</b>");
```

Comment: Yea, "lol".  I did read the question. Though I might update my answer since the OP edited his question several times.

Comment: Sorry, that came out wrong..   I meant as '+1 read(raed) the question throughly..  '     as in  'read as'....  but SO didnt let me type +1..  and english has same verb read, read read,,.

Comment: Oh then I misunderstood that, haha. No worries, it's all fine.

Comment: @cswl Just looked at your code. Not sure where you need help, since it seems to work as expected. But maybe shouldn't discuss that in the comments here lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83656/discussion-between-cswl-and-sebastian-nette).

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you need nothing more than this

```
price = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5]
totalPrice = 0
for(var k = 0; k < price.length; k++) {totalPrice += price[k];}
// gives 105
```

> But this just seems to append the price onto the end of the previous
>   output instead of adding together.

Make it zero:

```
totalPrice = 0
```

Comment: The array values aren't preset, they change each time the button is clicked. I have tried this way as well, it just seems to take the values from the first click and and the value from the second click (even though they are in the same index) and add them together. They also just append to one another in priceHere

Comment: Specify this properly in question that array values can change

Comment: I would think looking at price[0] = 8.45 * a; you could see that it has a possibility to change

Comment: If you clear that up in question, people can think more on solution than understanding your question

Answer (score 0):

Where do you declare `price` and `totalPrice`?

Here's an example of summing the values of an array:

```
var price = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // example array of prices
    totalPrice = 0, // initialize to 0 so totalPrice is a number
    k; // counter that you'll use in the loop

for (k = 0; k < price.length; k++) {
  totalPrice += price[k];
}

console.log(totalPrice); // 15
```

Note that JavaScript uses the `+` operator for both addition and string concatenation. It sounds like what is likely happening is that `totalPrice` has been set as a string (or [type coerced](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html) into one), and thus when you're meaning to add to a number, you're in fact concatenating a string.

Here's an example of what that looks like. Note that all of the code is identical, save for the assignment of a string (rather than a number) to totalPrice:

```
var price = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // example array of prices
    totalPrice = '0', // initialized as the string '0'
    k; // counter that you'll use in the loop

for (k = 0; k < price.length; k++) {
  totalPrice += price[k];
}

console.log(totalPrice); // '012345'
```

Comment: They are declared globally